# Formula with IF statement and condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, excel-2013

I am trying to use an excel formula to determine the proportion (`pDistance`) of the total `Distance` for each `Position` by `Site`.  For example if the (total) `Distance` was 50 and the `Position` was 10 the proportion of the total distance (`pDistance`) would be 0.2, the last `pDistance` of any `Site` should always be 1.  The formula I used (`=IF(B3<B2, 1, (B2/C2))`) mostly works, except that I have some values of `Position` that are -10.

In these cases every `Position` in that `Site` should have a value of 10 added to it before calculating the `pDistance`. Can this be done with one formula, that is calculate the `pDistance` and add 10 when necessary?  Or would it be best to make a dummy column first?  If creating a dummy column is the way to go, how does one use formula to do something until a condition is met (e.g. add 10 the `Position` until a 0 , or new `Site`, is reached)?

[image: excel 2013 screenshot of if statement with want of conditional statement]

Comment: Your row 9 criteria doesn't match row 2 criteria?

Comment: @PortlandRunner this did not work for me it produce the correct result inconsistently on the sample data from above.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am not sure what you are asking.  Row 9 is different from Row 2 because of the -10 Position in Site 395, that is not in Site 360.  I feel as though I explained this issue above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample data, I understand that for any Site which has a value of `-10` somewhere in column B, then the calculation of `(B / C)` needs to be `((B + 10) / C)`. (Although cell `D11` doesn't follow this, I'm assuming it's just a typo :) )

The formula below would work in this case:

> D2 = (SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$22=$A2)*($B$2:$B$22=-10))*10 + B2) / C2

This formula works as follows:

1. `SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$22=$A2)*($B$2:$B$22=-10))`

   --> This will return the total number of rows which contain the value of `A2` in column A and a `-10` in column B :

   - `($A$2:$A$22=$A2)` looks at all values in the cells between `A2` & `A22`, and finds which ones match `A2`. That is, it finds which rows that have the same Site number as the row where the formula is entered
   - `($B$2:$B$22=-10)` looks at all values in the cells between `B2` & `B22`, and finds which ones equal `-10`. That is, it finds all rows that have a Distance value of `-10`.
   - The `SUMPRODUCT` finds the overlap of these. So, it counts how many rows have both the right Site number and a distance value of `-10`.
2. This value is than multiplied by 10. If there were no -10 values paired with the site, then it is `0 * 10 = 0`. If there was one pair, it will be `1 * 10 = 10`.
3. That result is then added to `B2`, and then divided by `C2`.

Note: this formula assumes that there will only be a maximum of one `-10` value for a particular site. If there is more than one, then the `SUMPRODUCT` will return the total number of matches, and the calculation will be wrong (but the formula can be updated to correct this).

Also note that the formula refers to the ranges `$A$2:$A$22` and `$B$2:$B$22`. These ranges must match the first and last numerical entry in your data (and not include any text - this will break the `SUMPRODUCT` formula). The simplest way to handle this (if you don't want to have to update the formula when adding values at the end of data set) is to set up a defined range name and refer to that in the formula.

To apply the formula, just paste it into `D2`, and copy/drag the formula down into the cells below.

As a conclusion, I can recommend that you create a "dummy" / "helper" column to store the `(SUMPRODUCT * 10) + B2` results, and use this as the input for the division calculation. This will help to visualize and check the data that is being used for the calculation. It can be hidden until you want to check the values or change the formula in case the requirements change in the future.

Comment: this is a great explanation! However, I just needed to add this `=IF(B3<B2,1,...` to your formula to ensure that the last `Position` per `Site` always has the `pDistance` of 1.